# How does Bohmian Mechanics explain superconductivity?

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, superconductivity, phonons, bohmian-mechanics

I'm looking for sources that discuss how Bohmian Mechanics explains superconductivity. Are there still Cooper pairs? Phonons? I saw one vague reference to vortices, but no details. This is my first post here, so thanks in advance!

Comment: It was my understanding that Bohmian mechanics is the usual Schrodinger equation for the usual wavefunction but with some extra hidden variables that make measurement deterministic. Thus I would expect the phenomenology to be exactly the same, since you only need the wavefunction and its expectation values to diagnose superconductivity.

Comment: [Nikulov 2008](https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.4118).